# how to set the first day of the week in ngBootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

Hello I'm trying to set the sunday as the first day of the week in the ngbootstrap, I'm using the bootstrap sample code same as:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-6">
  <ngb-datepicker #d1 [(ngModel)]="model1" #c1="ngModel"></ngb-datepicker>

  <hr />
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="model1 = today">
    Select Today
  </button>
  <hr />

  <pre>Model: {{ model1 | json }}</pre>
  <pre>State: {{ c1.status }}</pre>
</div>
```

**TS**
export class DatepickerTodayComponent {

```
  date?: { year: number; month: number };

  model1?: string;

  constructor(
    private ngbCalendar: NgbCalendar,
    private dateAdapter: NgbDateAdapter<string>
  ) {}

  get today() {
    return this.dateAdapter.toModel(this.ngbCalendar.getToday())!;
  }
}
```

I don't know if exist a property to change it

Comment: use,e.g. `[firstDayOfWeek]="3"` (1=Monday,...7=sunday) see the [API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api)

Comment: Thank you so much